# Spring looks for .jsp instead of .ftl

Tags: spring-webflow, freemarker

I'm trying to use FreeMarker in my Spring Web Flow application. 
I configured my flow in directory flows/welcome/helloflow.xml and start.ftl representing start-state

FreeMarker configuration on sevlet-context.xml:

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
  <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/flows/welcome/"/>
</bean>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
  <property name="cache" value="false"/>
  <property name="prefix" value=""/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
</bean>

<bean name="/*" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
</bean>

<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" />

<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry">
  <webflow:flow-location path="/WEB-INF/flows/welcome/helloflow.xml"/>          
</webflow:flow-registry>
```

web.xml important parts:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>  

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>        

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>
      index.ftl
    </welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

helloflow.xml:

```
<view-state id="start">
    <transition on="next" to="end" />
</view-state>
<end-state id="end" />
```

I have also nothing-special-about-it file start.ftl reperesenting start state.

Then when I try to access

```
http://localhost:8080/flows/welcome/helloflow
```

it tells me "Problem accessing /WEB-INF/flows/welcome/start.jsp Not Found"
So it searches for start.jsp instead of start.ftl even though I configured Freemarker view resolver.

Comment: Please show your controller class, web.xml and complete spring bean configuration file.

Comment: OK, now here is full configuration listings

Answer (score 0):

In your web.xml you don't map your Beans configuration file to the Dispatcher Servlet.

You should either specify `contextConfigLocation` as an `init-param`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:<Location to>/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Or as a `context-param`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:<Location to>/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This could well fix your problem.